# Store harvested apple into stocks

Tags: c

Can anybody help me store harvested apple in each day into stocks, after harvest increment day by 1, only one harvest per day.

So far this is my code

```
void dispMenu();

int main() {        
    int choice = 0;
    int apple = 0, stocks, days = 1;

menu:
    clrscr();
    printf("Day %d\n", days++);
    dispMenu();

    scanf("%d", &choice);  

    if (choice == 1) {    
        printf("Enter Number of apples harvested: ");
        scanf("%d", &apple);        
    }

    stocks = apple;

    if (choice == 2) {    
        printf("Day    Stocks\n");
        printf("%2d     %4d\n", days, stocks);      
    }
    getch();
    goto menu;    
}

void dispMenu() {       
    printf("1. harvest\n");
    printf("2. View Stocks\n");
    printf("\nchoice: ");
}
```

for example:

```
Day 1 I input in harvest is 200
Day 2 I input in harvest is 150
Day 3 I input in harvest is 350
...days are infinite
```

when viewing the stocks it should display

```
 DAY   STOCKS
  1     200
  2     150
  3     350
```

Comment: You need to store the number of apples in an array. Right now you just copy the `apples` variable  into `stocks` variable which is useless. Concepts which you should learn: loops and arrays.

Comment: @Michael Walz what loop should i use for or while

Comment: It's up to you. But as you need to display an array from index 0 to days-1, a `for` loop is the most convenient.

Comment: Don't use `goto` for this, a simple loop is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize `stocks` to `0` and increment it by the amount harvested instead of just setting it.  In order to keep a listing with one line per day, you need an array.

You should also replace the `goto` with a loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void dispMenu(void) {       
    printf("1. harvest\n");
    printf("2. View Stocks\n");
    printf("\nchoice: ");
}

int main(void) {        
    int choice = 0;
    int apple = 0, days = 1;
    int stocks[100] = { 0 };

    for (;;) {
        clrscr();
        printf("Day %d\n", days);
        dispMenu();

        if (scanf("%d", &choice) != 1)
            break;

        if (choice == 1 && days < 100) {    
            printf("Enter Number of apples harvested: ");
            scanf("%d", &stocks[days]);
            days++;
        }
        if (choice == 2) {    
            printf("Day    Stocks\n");
            for (int i = 1; i < days; i++) {
                printf("%2d     %4d\n", i, stocks[i]);      
        }
        getch();
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: how to do the breakdown for stocks

DAY   STOCKS

  1     200

  2     150

  3     350

Comment: @iCe_Star: I updated the code above with an array for `stocks`.